# NEED to move workflow history to another web application

Tags: workflow

we have realized recently at a customer's that worklow history is disappearing, which is, as we know (now :(), by design, but we need to get the lost workflow history back. 
We restored the necessary web app from a 2 months old backup, the history is present there, but we cannot find any way to copy it to the actual site. The documents and libraries are the same (remember, I use a backup of a current web app). We cannot simply use that backup, because it is 2 months old.
We tried - in a test environment - also some database operations, but no luck. This wouldnt be acceptable in a production environment anyway.
Any help would be very appreciated.
Regards,
Ravie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to create a feature that would show the WFL history, thanks to this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointworkflow/thread/b15b27e2-3033-418b-9731-968273d7423e/

Answer (score 1):

What version of SharePoint are you using? If SharePoint 2010, you should be able to browse the content of database offline and able to export required items from there and then import it back to you live site.

If you want to disable the history clean up operation, you can do it. Visit this for more information: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662522.aspx

Also, if you want to migrate items from one list to another, you can try using SharePoint Content Migration Wizard: http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/.   I would suggest that you evaluate the configuration settings available while doing the export/import with this tool. The options are same as available with STSADM's -export -import operations.

Comment: WSS3. We disabled the cleanup, but this does not bring the history :)
Finally, we solved it thanks to this thread:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointworkflow/thread/b15b27e2-3033-418b-9731-968273d7423e/

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to restore the backup to another location, you should be able to iterate through the workflow history using web services and write that data anywhere it's needed.  Have a look @ spservices.codeplex.com for a head start.

Comment: Thank you, I wonder if you could be more specific? Which function do you suppose would fit our needs?
Thanks again.
Ravie.

Comment: I would start by looking at the UpdateListItems operation:
http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UpdateListItems&referringTitle=Lists

Once you grab the item info from the list, you can then update the other list with that information.  Make sense?

Comment: It's probably good to note, your best bet for reporting from Workflow is to write the events directly to an audit list.  That way you can control the information and not have to worry about it being automatically deleted.  Here's an example too:
http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2010/08/05/sharepoint-extending-the-dvwp-%E2%80%93-part-25-using-an-audit-trail-by-creating-list-items-with-spservices/